No aparece la primera letra subrayada en un boton con &
No aparece la primera letra subrayada en un botón con &.
Por ejemplo, el texto de un botón es "&Nuevo" pero al abrir el formulario sólo aparece "Nuevo" sin la N subrayada.
Recién cuando presiono la tecla Alt, aparecen todas las letras de los botones subrayadas.
A qué se debe?
Gracias

Eso que te sucede es el comportamiento normal, es decir es correcto que cuando presiones la tecla Alt aparezca el subrayado, ya que es esta tecla la que activa los accesos directos de teclado en menús y botones, no obstante puedes cambiar este comportamiento y hacer que el subrayado siempre aparezca, para esto debes hacer lo siguiente:

Abrir el Panel de control.

Clic en Centro de accesibilidad.

Seleccionar Facilitar el uso del teclado.

Marcar Subrayar los métodos abreviados de teclado y las teclas de
acceso.

Finalmente dar clic en Aplicar y Aceptar.



Gracias Japv. Me funcionó a la perfección.
